# new ruby on rails setup, issues with slow gem updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ubuntu-12.04

I am having a big issue with updating my gems on a new production server I am building.

I am running it on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I have rubygems version 1.8.24, ruby version 1.9.3-p125, rails version 3.2.3.

Whenever i run the command `gem update` or gem `update --system`, it took hours for it to complete the first time.

Any ideas as to why this would be slow?

I am trying to see if its something with our firewall; but when I watch the traffic coming from that specific server, I am not seeing any deny messages.

Below i have added the command line view when i did sudo gem install rails -V

This is not all the code it is just the last 1000 lines since i had a limit on my terminal window.

Hopefully this provides some more insight into what may be happening

[gem install rails verbose code](http://pastebin.com/cqmyxH6c)

Comment: Running plain `gem update` will build (two versions of!) the gems' documentation by default.  Adding the `--no-rdoc` and `--no-ri` options should give you at least some improvement - no need to have all that on a production server.

Comment: i will try that thanks! the only thing that still troubles me is that this took so long. When i run it locally it takes maybe 1 minute. My coworker tried the same thing and received the same result, approximately a minute for completion.

Comment: Hmm.  Sounds like there's something else going on, too.  Not installing the docs should help, but I doubt it's the root of your problem...

Comment: ya thats what i was thinking, it may have something to do with our local internet connection but i am not sure yet.